# Read MIME multipart message

Tags: java, httpresponse, mime, multipartform-data

I hope someone can help me with this. I'm sending a request to server like this:

```
ClientResponse cr = service.path(url)
.accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).get(ClientResponse.class);
```

As a response I'm receiving a multipart message which looks something like this:

```
------- =_aaaaaaaaaaA
Content-Type: text/plain; Content-Id: "name"

bkbfdkbfkdbfk3ik3ooijo


------- =_aaaaaaaaaaB
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; Content-Id: "image"

nkniha3q479894ph4934233
```

My question is how to read those body parts of that message by Id? I need to store every part of that message in a different place.

Comment: Which library do you use ?

Comment: If you aren't using some library, the header in your response should tell you the string used as a delimiter. Parse your body until you find a delimiter and store that, then keep looking.

Comment: I'm using Jersey. I've also tried with Apache HttpClient but without luck. I've was searching a lot and can't find anything useful.

Comment: @ZdravkoVajudin - see my answer on your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078347/handling-multipart-response-from-jersey-server-in-android-client).

Comment: @Perception I just saw it. Thank you :) I also found this interesting link: http://www.mozgoweb.com/posts/how-to-parse-mime-message-using-mime4j-library/